# Augmented Dickey Fuller test in Python with statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm performing an ADF test on several(~500) time series to test stationarity. So I need a quantitative way of choosing the correct number of lags for each one of them. One possible approach is to use, say, 80% of my sample for the test and to get the parameters of the regression in it and compute the ssr (sum of squares regression) and search for the minimum. However, this may lead to over fitting and in order to avoid it, this regression can then be applied to the remaining 20%  and calculate the ssr of this sub-sample. The number of lags that lead to the minimum value of this second ssr, should be the correct one.

The problem is that statsmodels documentation is less than incomplete (at least for a newbie like me!). For example, given the line

```
res = ts.adfuller(dUs, maxlag=max_lag_, autolag=None, regression='ct', store=True, regresults=True)
```

the regression coefficients are stored in res[3].resols.params but the order is unknown. I had to ask someone to run the test on one of my time series in R (which gives you the used formula and the corresponding coefficients like this

[R-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhD85.png)).

Python order of parameters seems to be (for a 'ct' regression) lag 1, lag diff 1, lag diff 2, ...lag diff N, intercept, time trend. I, then, re-construct the fitted series with the following code:

```
xFit[0:max_lag_ + 1] = dUs[0:max_lag_ + 1]
for i in range (max_lag_ + 1,xFit.size):
    xFit[i] = xFit[i-1] + res[3].resols.params[0] * xFit[i-1] + res[3].resols.params[res[3].resols.params.size - 2] +  res[3].resols.params[res[3].resols.params.size - 1] * t[i]
    for j in range(1,max_lag_ +1):
        xFit[i] = xFit[i] + res[3].resols.params[j] * lag[i-1-j]
```

Note that the lag variable is constructed from my dUs variable like this

```
lag = dUs[1:]-dUs[:-1]
```

The thing is that the xFit series and res[3].resols.fittedvalues are different! I think that it might has something to do with my initialization of the first max_lag_ data points (in fact, note that the res[3].resols.fittedvalues is max_lag_ + 1 shorter than the original series): I chose them to be equal to the original series. But I can' t figure out what exactly is going on. The difference between xFit and res[3].resols.params is HUGE:
[time-series-comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGNXJ.png). Note also that, increasing the lag number makes my fitting better up to some value, and then the series explodes. This does not happen with fittedvalues!

As a final test, I ran the ADF test on xFit; I understand this should lead to the res[3].resols.params I already got.

Given the line

```
res2 = ts.adfuller(xFit, maxlag=max_lag_, autolag=None, regression='ct', store=True, regresults=True)
```

the output of res2[3].resols.params is

[ -1.60231256e+00   4.23814175e-02  -4.15837300e-02   4.99642618e-02
  -6.92483339e+02   3.89141878e+00]

while res[3].resols.params is

[ -1.29269094e+00   2.11857016e-02  -5.82679110e-02  -2.09614163e-02
  -5.44413351e+02   2.69502722e+00]

I know that many of you would suggest to move to R but, a) I never used it (although I could learn) and b) getting software installed at work is not that easy and it could take me a lot of precious time.

Any ideas? any mistake I'm missing?

Thanks in advance,

C

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue (although I didn't had time to post it before!).
The thing is that R fits the difference series while Python fits the time series itself. That in combination with an error (xFit should be replaced with dUs in the reconstruction of the time series!) made everything weird as explained above. 
The right code is

```
for i in range (max_lag_ + 1,xFit.size):
    xFit[i] = res[3].resols.params[0] * dUs[i-1] +  res[3].resols.params[res[3].resols.params.size - 1]
for j in range(1,max_lag_ +1):
    xFit[i] = xFit[i] + res[3].resols.params[j] * lag[i-1-j]
```